# Likelihood function for spatial Poisson

Tags: likelihood, spatial, poisson-regression

The dependent variable in our data is the integer number of trips made in a time period. We can regress on socioeconomic attributes of the individual $X$. The most logical model for this is a Poisson or negative binomial count model,

$$P(y = h | X) = \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^h}{h!}$$

Where the mean of the of the Poisson distribution is $\lambda = e^{X\beta}$, or an exponentiated latent regression. The likelihood function for this model is

$$\mathcal{L}(\beta) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i\log(\lambda_i) - \exp(\lambda_i))$$

Now consider that instead, we have a spatial regression that we use for the latent mean estimation. If we consider that the mean follows a spatial dependence process $\lambda = e^{(I-\rho W)^{-1}X\beta}$, would this imply that the likelihood function is simply

$$\mathcal{L}(\beta) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i(I-\rho W)^{-1}X_i\beta - \exp((I-\rho W)^{-1}X_i\beta))$$

Is there something else that I must consider? Are there any useful references or existing model estimation code for this likelihood function?